# How to get line break in E-Mail from shellscript?

Tags: bash, perl, email, awk, sed

There is a shell script (bash) that check a csv file for lines that don't match a pattern and send a mail with the wrong lines. Thats works fine but while combine the wrong lines linux give a \r as line break, in the E-Mail there is no linebreak. So I try to send \r\n as line break but this has no effect, perl or bash delete this \n newline.

Here is a minimal working script as example:

```
SUBJECT="Error while parse CSV"
TO="rcpt@domain.tld"
wrongLines=$(perl -ne 'print "Row $.: $_\r\n" if not /^00[1-9]\d{4,}$/' $file)
MESSAGE="Error while parse following Lines, pattern dont match: \r\n $wrongLines"
echo $MESSAGE |od -c
```

The output of od is:

```
0000000   E   r   r   o   r       w   h   i   l   e       p   a   r   s
0000020   e       f   o   l   l   o   w   i   n   g       L   i   n   e
0000040   s   ,       p   a   t   t   e   r   n       d   o   n   t
0000060   m   a   t   c   h   :       \   r   \   n       R   o   w
0000100   2   :       4   9   2   7   8   3   8   7   4   3      \r   R
0000120   o   w       3   :       4   8   2   3   2   8   9   7   3   8
0000140      \r  \n
0000143
```

But what is the reason that in the od output the \n between the rows is deleted? I also try \x0D\x0A instead of \r\n but this also don't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use more quotes: `echo "$MESSAGE"`. And you _don't_ want `\r`.

Comment: Maybe you should read [the `echo` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1.html)? Or use [`printf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) instead?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf The sequence `\r\n` is the standard newline in many text-based protocols.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: my comment was mainly about using quotes… (and I'm not sure that _backslash_ followed by _r_ (or _n_) will do anything).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf With the correct options to `echo` (or when using `printf`) the backslash will work as expected in most other environments where newline and carriage return are introduced in such a way. The part about the quotes is correct and important though.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: that was a right suggestion. Add the quote and delete the \r\n add a \n on each line end. Please write an answer so I can mark this as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not using quotes!

Look:

```
$ a="A multi-line
input
variable"
$ echo $a
A multi-line input variable
$ echo "$a"
A multi-line
input
variable
$
```

Without quotes, you'll be victim of [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) and [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) (not illustrated in the example above).

Also, adding `\r` or `\n` (that is, verbatim *backslash* followed by *r* or *n*) is not going to help at all.

Conclusion: Quote every variable expansion! always! (unless you *really* mean a glob pattern — in which case you will also add a comment in the code to explain why you purposely didn't quote the expansion).

Side note: [don't use upper case variable names](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Parameters)!

> It is recommended you use lower-case names for your own parameters so as not to confuse them with the all-uppercase variable names used by Bash internal variables and environment variables.

Comment: The only strange thing was that the line break after the text and before concat the output has a line break also without the quote in the echo command.